# ruby - how to created SortedSet from Set?

Tags: ruby, set

If I have an array I can create a set (unique values) from it with

```
require 'set'
s = [11,12,3,2,3,4,3,5,89,1,2,3,4]
uniq_s = s.to_set # gives [11,12,3,2,4,5,89,1]
```

If I want the result to be sorted I *could* do this with
    sorted_s = s.sort

How could I also do this using a `SortedSet` ?
I tried using `array.to_sorted_set` but that doesn't exist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the existing set to `SortedSet.new`

Example:

```
irb(main):046:0> s = [11,12,3,2,3,4,3,5,89,1,2,3,4].to_set
=> #<Set: {11, 12, 3, 2, 4, 5, 89, 1}>
irb(main):047:0> sorted_s = SortedSet.new(s)
=> #<SortedSet: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 89}>
irb(main):048:0>
```

Comment: There is no need for the intermediate `to_set`. Just pass the original array directly to `SortedSet.new`

Comment: Te elaborate on spickermanns comment, `Set::new` and `SortedSet::new` accept any argument that is an instance of a class that includes the *Enumerable* module (`obj.kind_of? Enumerable` should be `true`). *SortedSet* has the additional requirement that elements in the enumerable should also respond to the comparison operator `<=>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also pass the set class as described in the [`#to_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Enumerable.html) documentation.

```
require 'set'
s = [11,12,3,2,3,4,3,5,89,1,2,3,4]
s.to_set(SortedSet)
#=> #<SortedSet: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 89}>
```